In a 2 arm pre-post RCT, is an interaction test on an ANOVA the same as a t-test of the change scores?
Say you have a 2-armed pre-test post-test control trial design. You want to test the effect of group allocation on the outcome variable. I simulated a version of this in R, using 3 different methods: 2x2 repeated measures ANOVA, ANCOVA with baseline as covariate, and unpaired t-test of the change in each group. I put the code below if anyone's interested. Please excuse how cluttered it is, I wasn't planning on showing the public.
What I found was that the p-values produced from the group x time interaction in the ANOVA were the exact same as those found with the unpaired t-test of change, even with changing up the parameters/sample sizes the data was simulated from.
So when there are only 2 arms and 2 time points, is the interaction test in a 2x2 ANOVA the exact same as an unpaired t-test of change?
It just seems weird to me that the ANOVA is the default test in these kind of studies, at least in the fields I'm aware of (sports nutrition and exercise science), if the main thing you are looking at can be accomplished via a simple t-test - because main effects of group and time are often not looked at anyway.
library(rstatix)
library(tidyverse)

#Set number of simulations
nsims <- 100

#Set parameters 
Pre_M_I <- 100
Pre_M_C <- 100
Pre_SD_I <- 15
Pre_SD_C <- 15
N_I <- 15
N_C <- 15
  
Change_M_I <- 20
Change_M_C <- 20
Change_SD_I <- 15
Change_SD_C <- 15

#set up empty variable to store the p-value from ANOVA 
p_anov <- numeric(nsims)

#set up empty variable to store the p-value from ANCOVA 
p_ancov <- numeric(nsims)

#set up empty variable to store the p-value from t-test
p_t <- numeric(nsims)

#set up empty variable to store the p-value from paired t-test
p_pt <- logical(nsims)

#run simulation
for(i in 1:nsims){
      pre_I <- rnorm(n = N_I, mean = Pre_M_I, sd = Pre_SD_I)
      pre_C <- rnorm(n = N_C, mean = Pre_M_C, sd = Pre_SD_C)
      post_I <- pre_I + rnorm(n = N_I, mean = Change_M_I, sd = Change_SD_I)
      post_C <- pre_C + rnorm(n = N_C, mean = Change_M_C, sd = Change_SD_C)
      data <- data.frame(pre_I, post_I, pre_C, post_C)
      
      data2 <- data %>%
        pivot_longer(
          cols = everything(),  # All columns will be pivoted
          names_to = "group_time",  # New column for group and time information
          values_to = "hypertrophy"  # New column for the dependent variable (measurements)
        )
      
      # Split the group_time column into group and time columns
      data2 <- data2 %>%
        separate(
          col = "group_time",  # The column to separate
          into = c("time", "group"),  # Names of the new columns
          sep = "_",  # Split the column at the underscore
          remove = TRUE  # Remove the original group_time column
        )
      
      data2$id <- rep(1:(nrow(data2)/2), each = 2)
      
      #making df for ancova
      data3 <- data2 %>%
        pivot_wider(
          id_cols = c('id', 'group'),  # Columns to keep as identifiers
          names_from = 'time',  # Column containing the 'Pre' and 'Post' identifiers
          values_from = 'hypertrophy',  # Column containing the measurements
          names_prefix = ''  # Prefix for the new column names (optional)
        )

      
      anov <- anova_test(data = data2, dv = hypertrophy, wid = id, between = group, within = time)
      
      p_anov[i] <- anov$p[3]
      
      #now for ancova
      
      ancov <- lm(formula = post ~ pre + group, data = data3)
      
      ancov_summary <- summary(ancov)
      
      p_ancov[i] <- ancov_summary$coefficients["group1", "Pr(>|t|)"]
      
      #now for t-test
      data4 <- data
      data4$change_I <- data4$post_I - data4$pre_I
  data4$change_C <- data4$post_C - data4$pre_C
      data4 <- data4 %>% 
        select("change_I", "change_C")
      data4 <- data4 %>% 
        pivot_longer(
          cols = c(change_I, change_C),
          names_to = "Group",
          values_to = "Change"
        )
      t <- t.test(Change ~ Group, var.equal = FALSE, data = data4)
      p_t[i] <- t$p.value
      
      
      pt_I <- t.test(data$pre_I, data$post_I, paired = TRUE)
      pt_C <- t.test(data$pre_C, data$post_C, paired = TRUE)
      I_p <- pt_I$p.value
  C_p <- pt_C$p.value
      p_pt[i] <- (I_p < 0.05) & (C_p >= 0.05)
}


#calculating power for each
anov_power <- sum(p_anov<0.05)/nsims
ancov_power <- sum(p_ancov<0.05)/nsims
t_power <- sum(p_t<0.05)/nsims
pt_power <- sum(p_pt == TRUE)/nsims
pt_correct <- sum((p_pt == TRUE) & (p_ancov < 0.05))/nsims


#making histograms for each
hist(p_anov,
     breaks = 20,
     main = "ANOVA",
     xlab = "p-value",
     ylab = "frequency")

hist(p_ancov,
     breaks = 20,
     main = "ANCOVA",
     xlab = "p-value",
     ylab = "frequency")

hist(p_t,
     breaks = 20,
     main = "t.test",
     xlab = "p-value",
     ylab = "frequency")

anov_power
ancov_power
t_power
pt_power
pt_correct```


Your simulations do not include an actual baseline effect, so correcting for that will matter very little here -- but that is rarely true in practice or at least not often an assumption you will want to make. In most studies you don't want to correct for just the baseline (randomization strata would be in there almost by default), or there is more than one post-baseline observation and you don't want to use just a single one; all of these require more complex models that a t-test.

What do you mean by a baseline effect? Changing the parameters to be different at baseline, or changing the mean differences between groups still results in the exact same p-values. I'm aware that often there are more than 2 groups of more than one post-baseline observation but in sports science the 2x2 design is pretty common.

I mean that the change depends on the value at baseline (the latter is prognostic). This is quite common in real studies to varying degrees, or again you'd not usually assume that it isn't the case (a model that allows for such effect loses very little efficiency if it isn't there as you've discovered). Both FDA and EMA have guidances that mandate or even require correction for baseline value in such analyses.
